# What's For Multiplication...

Tags: notation

As summation symbol ($\sum$) is for summing up terms, is there a similar notation for multiplication (except factorial notation)?

Comment: $\prod$ is the multiplicative counterpart to $\sum$. See [Capital Pi Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication#Capital_pi_notation)

Comment: It is the Pi Function symbol, right?

Comment: I got it...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\prod$ (`\prod`) is the multiplicative analogue of $\sum$. It multiplies things together, where multiplication is assumed commutative.

But there's more! For some other commutative binary operations, the result of applying that operation to a list of objects may be denoted in a $\sum$-like notation, but with an enlarged operator taking $\sum$'s place. For example, $\bigwedge$ performs a logical AND ($\wedge$) of whatever follows, $\bigvee$ logical OR ($\vee$) and $\bigoplus$ logical XOR ($\oplus$).

Comment: Hey, may I know what AND, OR & XOR stand for? I don, t know...

Comment: @Some1 They correspond to the `& | ^` operators in C and C++. Bitwise functions.

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), @Some1